# How to apply jQuery-autocomplete-ui with space

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have used "https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/" into one of my web application. Using this plugin I want to display all possible results fetch from JSON response, but I am not able to do this.

In my application, I am fetching addresses from Melissa using its API for getting the address to autocomplete. I have used "https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/" for auto-complete. I am calling Mellissa's autocomplete API if the user has press at least 1 space. but I am not able to display the list but if I add any single character after space I am able to get autocomplete UI properly.

```
var stringLength = hasWhiteSpace(address);
if(stringLength){
    var url = "https://expressentry.melissadata.net/web/ExpressFreeForm";
    url += '?' + $.param({
    'id': "***********",
    'ff' : $(this).val(),
    'format': "json",
    'maxrecords':4
    });

$.each( data.Results, function( key, val ) {
   var addressId = val.Address.AddressKey;
   var addressData = val.Address.AddressLine1 + ', ' + val.Address.City + ', ' + val.Address.State + ', ' + val.Address.PostalCode;
   addressArray.push(addressData);
});

  $( "#deliveryStreetAddress" ).autocomplete({
    source: addressArray                       
  });
}
```

Above code generate proper UI for auto-complete if I add at least 1 character after space otherwise it does not work. e.g. if I type "36th " then I am able to get an array of addresses but it is not rendered in UI, but if I type "36th a" then I am able to get an array of addresses as well as that list is also rendered in UI. So can anyone help me how to do this?